# Youtube analytics api issue

Tags: youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

Trying to get the youtube anaytics channel report from this scope:
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly

and two channel IDs

1. UC2QjLUbr7XeJpiYgflSuZ-w
2. UCH8FFDRgoEtYGm00oqIADUQ

First channel id worked perfectly.
Second id shows me this error (below image), any ideas?

Many Thanks

[image]

> Forbidden [403] Errors [ Message[Forbidden] Location[ - ]
>   Reason[forbidden] Domain[global] ]

Comment: Please put the actual text of the error in your question, not an image of the text.

Comment: Forbidden [403]
Errors [
        Message[Forbidden] Location[ - ] Reason[forbidden] Domain[global]
]

Comment: Can youtube support answer this question please. Thanks!